# how to compress user uploaded image with Pillow in Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-imaging-library

how would you compress the image when the user uploads

```
from PIL import Image

class photo(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    uploader = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    image_url = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Losslessly compressing images on django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33077804/losslessly-compressing-images-on-django)

Answer (score 0):

Do in save method

```
from PIL import Image

class photo(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    uploader = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    image_url = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super(photo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        img = Image.open(instance.image_url.path)
        img.save(instance.image_url.path,quality=20,optimize=True)
        return instance
```

The 'optimize' flag will reduce its size as much as possible.